# Random number based on probability python

Tags: python, random, probability

Hi I have done reseatch and I believe I ended up in the right direction when I ended up at this thread:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117241/

> > Basically my question is: what is the code in the link doing line by line. You could potentially ignore all that I wrote below if your explanation makes me understand what the code in the link does to a satisfactory extent.

I BELIEVE that the code at that link generates a random number BUT the random number is directly related to the probability.

In my own code I am attempting to take a "number" and its probability of appearing, and get an output "number", that will appear according to the probability. I know this is confusing but if you look at the link above then I hope it will be clear what I am trying to do. My code below is in reference to the link above.

so in my program, these are my global variables:

```
HIGH= 3
MED= 2
LOW= 1
```

This is the list I am working with:

```
n= [LOW,lowAttackProb).(MED,medAttackProb),(HIGH,highAttackProb)]
#lowAttackProb,med...,etc. are based on user input are just percents converted to decimals that add up to 1 in every case
```

This is how I implemented the random code as per the link above:

```
x= random.uniform(0,1)
for alevel,probability in n:
    if x<probability:
        break
    x=x-probability
return alevel
```

I am unsure exactly what is happening inside the for loop and what x=x-probability is doing.

Lets say that x=0.90

and that in my list, the chance of the second list entry occuring is 0.60, then, since x (is less than)probability is False(im not too sure what if x(is less than)probability even does), the code moves on to n=n-probability.

I really hope this makes sense. If it does not please let me know what is unclear and I will try to fix it up. Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: `n = n-probabbility` does __not__ make sense, because `n` is a list, and `probability` is a number. You should be getting a `TypeError` running it. Note that you didn't mention what exactly your problem with the code is: does it give wrong results, or an error message, or what. Consider [edit]ing the question to include that info.

Comment: my apologies, i changed it to x.

Comment: Use `x = x - probability` instead of `n = n - probability`.

Comment: still, what does it do exactly, the code that is,... line by line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code implements the selection of event taking probabilities of possible events into account. Here is the idea behind it.

There are three events (or levels as you call them), `LOW`, `MED`, `HIGH`, with certain nonzero probability each, and all probabilities sum up to exactly 1. Using standard means of Python one can generate a random number between 0 and 1. So how can we "map" them to each other? Lets align our probabilities (lets call them L, M, and H for brevity) along the numbers line  the following way:

`0__________________L______________L+M_________________________L+M+H ( = 1)`

Now taking our randomly generated number `x` we can say that

1. If x lies in interval [0, L] then the first event occurred.
2. If x lies in half-interval (L, L+M] then the second event occurred.
3. If x lies in half-interval (L+M, L+M+H] then the third event occurred.

The code you are asking about simply matches `x` to one of the intervals and returns the corresponding event (or level).

Comment: Thank you, very,very,very well explained. Do you think you can join me in chat for a brief question related to the same code?@Andrei

Comment: @SajSeesSound, sure, just post a link here.

Comment: @SajSeesSound, here we go: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20744/random-number-based-on-probability-python

Comment: As a side note, this function will be faster if you order the list  from highest probability to lowest probability.